# Vue variable isn't rendering what exists in memory unless I use this workaround

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have code to display the selected option. You'll notice that there's a `v-model="selectedOption.value"` and a `{{selectedOption.value}}`

```
<h6 class="label">Select {{selectedOption.option_type}}: {{selectedOption.value}}</h6>
<span v-for="option in product.itemOptions">
  <label v-if="option.opt_type === selectedOption.option_type">
    <span>{{option.ito_notes}}</span>
    <input type="radio" :name="option.opt_type" :value="option.ito_notes" v-model="selectedOption.value" />
    <img :src="optionImage(option.vendid, option.option_pk)" class="option_image image is-48x48">
  </label>
</span>
```

You'd expect these to match, but in this case it's not, as demonstrated in this screenshot below comparing the browser window to the Chrome Vue Dev Tool Plugin.

[image: Demonstration of syncing not working]

But by adding `@change="nothing()"` to the input, having it trigger a toggle that is used in a v-if for `<span v-if="genericToggle"></span>`, the `{{selectedOption.value}}` is rendering on change. So my template becomes:

```
<h6 class="label">Select {{selectedOption.option_type}}: {{selectedOption.value}}</h6>
<span v-if="genericToggle"></span>
<span v-for="option in product.itemOptions">
  <label v-if="option.opt_type === selectedOption.option_type">
    <span>{{option.ito_notes}}</span>
    <input type="radio" :name="option.opt_type" :value="option.ito_notes" v-model="selectedOption.value"  @change="nothing()"/>
    <img :src="optionImage(option.vendid, option.option_pk)" class="option_image image is-48x48">
  </label>
</span>
```

And the `nothing()` method is simply this:

```
nothing() {
  this.genericToggle = !this.genericToggle;
},
```

I am using Vue 2.5.16.

**Why is `{{selectedOption.value}}` not rendering the value the browser has in memory, and how can I fix this properly?**

*Updates:*

`selectedOptions` is property of `product`, and property is initialized as `null` and then updated via ajax on load with an object that contains `selectedOptions` as a property.

Comment: Show your data function where selectedOption defined. Most likely its because -> https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @Aldarund It's a property of `product`, and property is initialized as `null` and then updated via ajax on load with an object that contains `selectedOptions` as a property.

Comment: well since its null it would be because the link i posted above. You need to use Vue.set/this.$set

Comment: @Aldarund After some playing around, that was exactly it, and the solutions in the doc work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aldarund for linking to this explanation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue more cleanly by running this on change of the input.

```
updateSelectOptionValue(index, value) {
  this.product = Object.assign({}, this.product, this.product);
},
```

This should be refactored to be more targeted so it doesn't reassign the whole object, but the basic idea is here.